# How to hide desktop from Ubuntu Desktop Applications UI

Tags: bash, desktop-environments, .desktop, xdg-open, xdg

I found the following link for changing file types application:

https://superuser.com/questions/21626/ubuntu-change-the-default-program-used-to-open-a-type-of-file

**Here is the command for associating the file type "`application/pdf`" with the "`kde-kpdf.desktop`" :**

```
$xdg-mime query default application/pdf
AdobeReader.desktop
$xdg-mime default kde-kpdf.desktop application/pdf
$xdg-mime query default application/pdf
kde-kpdf.desktop
```

I just want to `double-click` the "*.pdf" and then open with "kde-kpdf.desktop",

but I want to hide the "`kde-kpdf.desktop`" from the Ubuntu desktop applications list as shown below **(I downloaded the image from Internet, it doesn't contain the kde-kpdf.desktop icon in it)**:

[image]

Is it possible for hiding the specified `*.desktop` file from Ubuntu Applications List UI? How to hide the desktop but still allowing `double-click` the file-type to open with that application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**LOCATING .desktop FILE:**

Most of the time the .desktop file for the application you want to hide from the app grid is located in /usr/share/applications, however, if it is not there run

```
$find / -name "*application_name*.desktop" 2>/dev/null
```

to locate the desired desktop file. Here replace application_name with the keyword that would specify your application. In this case it would be

```
$find / -name "*kde-kpdf*.desktop" 2>/dev/null
```

The `2>/dev/null` part just redirects stderr (2) into the /dev/null file thereby removing permission errors from your console and deleting them.

**CHANGING .desktop FILE TO REMOVE ICON FROM APPLICATION GRID:**

Edit the app.desktop file with the text editor of choice and add the line `NoDisplay=true` under the `[Desktop Entry]` line.

This will remove the application icon from the app grid, but will keep an option to open files with this application. To completely hide your application replace the `NoDisplay=true` line with `Hidden=true`.

In case the application is not removed from grid reight away reboot your system.

Answer (score 0):

Thereis a key for desktop files to hide from menu.

cp the desktop file to $HOME/.local/share/applications/ and add

```
NoDisplay=true
```

This way I hide all wine desktop files; except for the games of course.